# How can I run my integration tests against two different databases?

Tags: c#, nunit, integration-testing

Our solution has two different Database Providers, both located in separate projects. They both inherit a common `IDbProvider` that is located in our core project.

```
namespace OurApp.Data
{
    public interface IDbProvider
    {
       // truncated
    }
}
```

```
namespace OurApp.Data.SqlServer
{
    public class DbProvider : IDbProvider {}
}
```

```
namespace OurApp.Data.Sqlite
{
    public class DbProvider : IDbProvider {}
}
```

The databases have to be identical in functionality, and we've already got integration tests working against the `SqlServer.DbProvider`.

Currently, all RepositoryTests inherit from a base class.

```
public abstract class RepositoryTestsBase
{
    protected IDbConnectionProvider Connection;
    protected IDbProvider DbProvider;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        // Need to create a new connection to the server and make sure there is no database
        ConnectionStringSettings dbConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databaseConnection"];
        string testDatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseName"];

        Connection = new DbConnectionProvider(dbConnection.ConnectionString, dbConnection.ProviderName);
        DbProvider = new DbProvider(Connection, testDatabaseName);
    }
```

I'd really ***hate*** to have to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>  all of my integration tests only to change the DbProvider.

Is there a way to run all of the integration tests twice while simply injecting a different DbProvider for each run? I'd like to be able to (obviously) do this in our Powershell builds, but also in the IDE.

My initial thought is to create two public methods and one private method, injecting the appropriate db provider.

```
[Test]
public void ShouldDoStuff_SQLServer() {
    var dbProvider = sqlserver.DbProvider;
    ShouldDoStuff(dbprovider);
}

[Test]
public void ShouldDoStuff_Sqlite() {
    var dbProvider = sqlite.DbProvider;
    ShouldDoStuff(dbprovider);
}

private void ShouldDoStuff (IDbProvider dbprovider){
    // Assert
}
```

Comment: Which testing framework are you using?

Comment: I've updated my question. We're using nunit.

Comment: There are multiple ways. But it is not possible to suggest a concrete way without knowing some details (which testing framework, existing code etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution might be to used parametized tests. The idea being that your test has different data passed to it each run, thus allowing you to run tests twice, once against each database.

Take a look at http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.2 to see if it will suit your needs here.

In your case you might have something like:

```
static IDbProvider[] DbProviders = new IDbProvider[] 
{
    sqlserver.DbProvider,  
    sqlite.DbProvider
};

[Test, TestCaseSource("DbProviders")]
public void TestMethod(IDbProvider dbProvider)
{
    ShouldDoStuff(dbprovider);
}
```

Alternatively, to run all tests in the class against the two providers, try something like this:

```
[TestFixture(0)]
[TestFixture(1)]
public class RepositoryTests
{
    private IDbProvider _provider;

    public IDbProvider(int index)
    {
        _provider = IDbProvider[index];
    }


    static IDbProvider[] DbProviders = new IDbProvider[] 
    {
        sqlserver.DbProvider,  
        sqlite.DbProvider
    };

    [Test]
    public void TestMethod(IDbProvider dbProvider)
    {
        ShouldDoStuff(_provider);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I've updated my question for further details. Is it possible to parameterize the `SetUp` only? What would it look like getting them to run twice?

Comment: In the `TestMethod`, I'd just `foreach(var dbp in dbProvider) ShouldDoStuff(dbprovider)`? Or does the TestCaseSource know to call it twice?

Comment: No need for a foreach. NUnit will run your test method twice, once for each value in DbProviders.

Comment: Ok so both of the answers now make perfect sense, but is there a way to do this on SetUp rather than in every single test?

Comment: I just refactored some code to use this model.  I was looping for an xml file for "expected results", and while about 2000 tests were being run, it only showed up as 1 in the CI webpage results.  Now its showing 2000 tests.  Took 10 minutes, but our NUnit tests just went out the wazoo!  Thanks.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell NUnit supports parametized test fixtures (see http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.6.2), but only supports hard-coded values. So I don't think it would be of use for you.

Comment: So yeah, this approach is going to be how I do it, it's just painful to have to rewrite EVERY test to setup the `_Repository` inside rather than just a single `SetUp` *sad panda*

Comment: were *(obviously)* injecting the `DbProvider` into the Repository.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell, I just suddenly realised how you could run the whole fixture twice. I've updated my answer to reflect the idea. Pass 0 and 1 in as parameters and use those as indexes to set up the correct provider. Let me know if it works as I think it's a technique I could use too. Sorry if there are mistakes: I just typed it on a phone! :)

Comment: Sorry, I took a break for lunch. I have a different idea. I'll create an Object that contains all of the SetUp data that I use for my tests. Then I'll create an IEnumerable Provider that yields all of the goods. Then I'll pass the complete object as a parameter so that I don't have to bloat my tests.

Answer (score 2):

You could use data-driven testing in combination with a Value source along these lines:

```
public IEnumerable Providers()
{
    yield return new OurApp.Data.SqlServer.DbProvider();
    yield return new OurApp.Data.Sqlite.DbProvider();
}

[Test]
public void MyTest([ValueSource("Providers")] IDbProvider provider)
{
    // Test code...
}
```

The test method will get called once for each object you return from your value source.

See NUnit documentation [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=valueSource&r=2.5)
Of course you need to also provide the db config stuff in your test project's configuration file.

HTH
Thomas

Comment: our DB config stuff is currently happening in a Setup. Are you saying it needs to move to a config file?

Comment: Not necessarily. You only need to make sure that the providers that are returned from your value source are correctly initialized. You could do it per code as well, even directly in the 'Provider' enumerator...

Comment: Ok so both of the answers now make perfect sense, but is there a way to do this on SetUp rather than in every single test?

Comment: Yes. See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it along these lines:

```
[TestFixture]
public class RepositoryTests
{
    protected IDbConnectionProvider Connection_SQLServer;
    protected IDbConnectionProvider Connection_SQLLite;
    protected string testDatabaseName_SQLServer;
    protected string testDatabaseName_SQLLite;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        // init both providers and db-names
    }

    public IEnumerable Providers()
    {
        yield return new SqlServer.DbProvider(testDatabaseName_SQLServer, Connection_SQLServer);
        yield return new Sqlite.DbProvider(testDatabaseName_SQLLite, Connection_SQLLite);
    }

    // Do tests
```